# Why does the Joker always use a knife?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight

In The Dark knight, except for when the Joker had to use big weapons for different reasons, we always saw him using a small knife.

Why does he prefer a knife?

Like we know Batman does not use any gun anytime because it is his own rule. Does Joker follow such a rule? I am not aware of the comic version though! If possible explain it in the scope of the movie, otherwise if there is any special reason according to comics, don't hesitate to share it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is in Joker's speech

> "Do you want to know why I use a knife? You see, guns are too quick.
>   You can't savor all of the little...emotions. In their last moments,
>   people show you who they really are. So in a way...I knew your friends
>   better than you ever did. Would you like to know which of them were
>   cowards?"

I think the cartoon or comics I got to know about doesn't indicate any connection between knife and Joker(may be I missed any!). But he is generally seen using guns like this.

[image]

I remember a cartoon film where this funny Bang rod used as a knife like substance for killing by him. In Nolan's series concern, it's Nolan's choice to use knife(for may be realistic tone!).